# AngularJS Dynamically change height based on width

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a table printed via `ng-repeat`, and my goal is to make every single `td` in `tbody`  square. All the `td`s are equal in width, so I only need to check the first one to make changes. However, the page is dynamic so the width of `table` and therefore the `td` will change on window resize.

I have stylesheet in `head`.

```
<style type="text/css">.squerify>tr{height:60px;}</style>
```

This is used to change the height via:

```
document.styleSheets[1].cssRules[0].style.height=document.querySelector('.squerify td').offsetWidht+"px";
```

This works on its own, but I wonder how to get angular to tell me, that the `td` has changed its width (here I was thinking about the `'onresize'` on window event).

Well, `onresize` might work now, but how about the initialization?
I have not found a way to let angular to tell me that it finished all its work.
PS.: The table is in view, if that changes anything...

The questions are as follow:

- Is there a better way to check for the page resize in angular?
- What to use for the initialization of table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who would like to know how to do square elements:

1. We need a base element (div will do it) give it class (I will use square), this one will be square:

   ```
   <div class="square"></div>
   ```
2. We put an img tag inside: (the "data:..." is needed, don't remove it, it is 1x1px transparent img)
3. We need a bit of css:

   ```
   .square img{
       width: 100%;
       height: auto;
       border: 0;
   }

   .square *:not(img){
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       right: 0;
       bottom: 0;
       left: 0;
   }
   ```
4. That is it, easy right?